# I'm looking to setup a NNTP cache/proxy server primarily for header caching on linux. Which one is recommended?

Tags: linux, proxy, cache, usenet, newsgroups

My requirement is that the News NNTP cache and proxy server must be able to cache headers without downloading the articles. i.e only download articles if requested.

There is a mention about Caching/Proxy NNTP servers at http://www.spack.org/wiki/NntpServers

I've read up on few Caching/Proxy servers, but it seems like they need to be setup by downloading the articles for configured group.

So, without setting up a Full-fledged NNTP server, can this be achieved.

Comment: And the question is...?

Comment: Edited title. Hopefully header will be more meaningful.